# Consultar por un valor de la tabla en formato Clase ajax poo con extends

Tags: php, ajax, poo, clase

Tengo este problema y quiero consultar directamente, me sale error, si alguno supiera la manera de hacerlo mejor, me gustaria me indiquen.

```
$user = $db->facultad->getAll("SELECT cuenta, contraseña FROM cuentas WHERE cuenta='MAT2018A001'");         
if (!empty($user)){
   $password = $user[0]['contraseña'];
   echo $password."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Por favor explica que error te sale. ¿Estás usando algún framework o librería?

Comment: Confieso que no logro entender qué significa *en formato Clase ajax poo con extends*

Comment: Confiezo que poner las cosas aqui aclara las ideas y si alguIen te ayuda mucho mejor... y encontre el problema.  **$db = $this->create_db();**, # quedaria el procedimiento si fuera directo.
$db = adoNewConnection('pdo');
$dsnString= 'host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_FACULTA.';';
$db->connect('mysql:'.$dsnString, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);